# How to open a very long link from batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hyperlink, prompt

I write to you because I should create a small batch file to open a very long link containing symbols including &.

At the moment I'm trying to use the following structure:

```
explorer "www.mylink.com etc"
```

But not all the link is opened but it is truncated in half and therefore the server gives me an error reply.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve the problem?
I point out that I cannot shorten the link via a third party site as it contains confidential information.

Thank you in advance for your support. I'm sure it will be a very simple thing for those who are familiar with the language.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your feedback. It was easier then i thought, it worked in this way (i always need to open the link from Internet Explorer):

```
start iexplore.exe  "https://myurl.com/etc%%etc7"
```